# I need help filtering data that are only available in 2 categories (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi

I have data for hotel rates on 2 different booking channels (Maqam and Maqam Umrah)

[image: Figure 1]

As shown in figure 1, some rates are not available on one booking channel.

What I want to achieve is to filter only the rates that are available on both booking channels, can anyone help? :)

Here is the shape of the raw data (Figure 2):

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write a measure to display 1 for hotels having both Maqam and Maqam Umrah and 0 for hotels having only Maqam or Maqam Umrah

[image]

Then filter table with values 1

[image]

Then use resulted table for matrix visual

[image]